# Generate Table with Greek letters and multicolumns in rstudio for latex

Tags: tables, multicolumn, r, greek, rstudio

With the commands:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, results='asis',message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(xtable)

url <- 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/master/'
dt1 <- read.table(paste0(url, 'sim50.txt'), header = TRUE)
attach(dt1)
dt2 <- read.table(paste0(url, 'sim200.txt'), header = TRUE)
attach(dt2)
dt3 <- read.table(paste0(url, 'sim1000.txt'), header = TRUE)
attach(dt3)

gamma0=1.23
gamma1=0.07
gamma2=1.05
#gamma3=0.7
beta0=1.18
beta1=0.23
beta2=0.25
phi1 <- 0.69
rho <- 0.03
truevalue <- c(gamma0,gamma1,gamma2,beta0,beta1,beta2,phi1,rho)

eqm=function(x,theta){ 
  N=length(x)
  sqrt(sum(((x-theta)^2))/N)}
m  <- dt1
m2 <- dt2
m3 <- dt3

eqmest=c(eqm(x=m[,1],theta=truevalue[1]),
         eqm(x=m[,2],theta=truevalue[2]),
         eqm(x=m[,3],theta=truevalue[3]),
         eqm(x=m[,4],theta=truevalue[4]),
         eqm(x=m[,5],theta=truevalue[5]),
         eqm(x=m[,6],theta=truevalue[6]),
         eqm(x=m[,7],theta=truevalue[7]),
         eqm(x=m[,8],theta=truevalue[8]))

eqmest2=c(eqm(x=m2[,1],theta=truevalue[1]),
          eqm(x=m2[,2],theta=truevalue[2]),
          eqm(x=m2[,3],theta=truevalue[3]),
          eqm(x=m2[,4],theta=truevalue[4]),
          eqm(x=m2[,5],theta=truevalue[5]),
          eqm(x=m2[,6],theta=truevalue[6]),
          eqm(x=m2[,7],theta=truevalue[7]),
          eqm(x=m2[,8],theta=truevalue[8]))

eqmest3=c(eqm(x=m3[,1],theta=truevalue[1]),
          eqm(x=m3[,2],theta=truevalue[2]),
          eqm(x=m3[,3],theta=truevalue[3]),
          eqm(x=m3[,4],theta=truevalue[4]),
          eqm(x=m3[,5],theta=truevalue[5]),
          eqm(x=m3[,6],theta=truevalue[6]),
          eqm(x=m3[,7],theta=truevalue[7]),
          eqm(x=m3[,8],theta=truevalue[8]))
parameter <- c("gamma0 (mu2)","gamma1 (mu2)", "gamma2 (mu2)", "beta0 (mu1)", "beta1 (mu1)",
               "beta2 (mu1)","phi1 (sd)","rho (cor)")
dt <- data.frame(Parameters=parameter,VV=truevalue,Mean=cbind(colMeans(dt1)),EQM=eqmest,
                Mean=cbind(colMeans(dt2)),EQM=eqmest2,Mean=cbind(colMeans(dt3)),
                EQM=eqmest3)
kable(dt, digits = 5, align = c('c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c'))

print(xtable(dt,digits=c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5), caption = "",align = rep("c",9)), 
      caption.placement = "top", include.rownames = FALSE, type = "latex")
```
````

I generate the following table in rstudio to use in my latex file:

[image]

It's possible generate the table below, with Greek letters and multicolumn, with the command `xtable` in Rstudio software?

[image]

If not, is it possible to generate this simpler:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After help of @nebi, it was possible to complete the table as desired. Just delete all "NA" and "clear" manually in latex.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, results='asis',message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(xtable)

url <- 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/master/'
dt1 <- read.table(paste0(url, 'sim50.txt'), header = TRUE)
attach(dt1)
dt2 <- read.table(paste0(url, 'sim200.txt'), header = TRUE)
attach(dt2)
dt3 <- read.table(paste0(url, 'sim1000.txt'), header = TRUE)
attach(dt3)

gamma0=1.23
gamma1=0.07
gamma2=1.05
#gamma3=0.7
beta0=1.18
beta1=0.23
beta2=0.25
phi1 <- 0.69
rho <- 0.03
truevalue <- c(gamma0,gamma1,gamma2,beta0,beta1,beta2,phi1,rho)

eqm=function(x,theta){ 
  N=length(x)
  sqrt(sum(((x-theta)^2))/N)}
m  <- dt1
m2 <- dt2
m3 <- dt3

eqmest=c(eqm(x=m[,1],theta=truevalue[1]),
         eqm(x=m[,2],theta=truevalue[2]),
         eqm(x=m[,3],theta=truevalue[3]),
         eqm(x=m[,4],theta=truevalue[4]),
         eqm(x=m[,5],theta=truevalue[5]),
         eqm(x=m[,6],theta=truevalue[6]),
         eqm(x=m[,7],theta=truevalue[7]),
         eqm(x=m[,8],theta=truevalue[8]))

eqmest2=c(eqm(x=m2[,1],theta=truevalue[1]),
          eqm(x=m2[,2],theta=truevalue[2]),
          eqm(x=m2[,3],theta=truevalue[3]),
          eqm(x=m2[,4],theta=truevalue[4]),
          eqm(x=m2[,5],theta=truevalue[5]),
          eqm(x=m2[,6],theta=truevalue[6]),
          eqm(x=m2[,7],theta=truevalue[7]),
          eqm(x=m2[,8],theta=truevalue[8]))

eqmest3=c(eqm(x=m3[,1],theta=truevalue[1]),
          eqm(x=m3[,2],theta=truevalue[2]),
          eqm(x=m3[,3],theta=truevalue[3]),
          eqm(x=m3[,4],theta=truevalue[4]),
          eqm(x=m3[,5],theta=truevalue[5]),
          eqm(x=m3[,6],theta=truevalue[6]),
          eqm(x=m3[,7],theta=truevalue[7]),
          eqm(x=m3[,8],theta=truevalue[8]))
parameter <- c("$\\gamma_{1}$","$\\gamma_{2}$", "$\\gamma_{3}$", "$\\beta_{1}$", "$\\beta_{2}$","$\\beta_{3}$","$\\phi$","$\\rho$")
dt <- data.frame(Parâmetros=parameter,VV=truevalue,Clear=rep("NA",8),Média=cbind(colMeans(dt1)),EQM=eqmest,Clear=rep("NA",8),Média=cbind(colMeans(dt2)),EQM=eqmest2,Clear=rep("NA",8),Média=cbind(colMeans(dt3)),EQM=eqmest3)

print(xtable(dt,digits=c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5), caption = " ",align = rep("c",12)), 
      caption.placement = "top", include.rownames = FALSE,include.colnames = FALSE,
      type = "latex", 
      sanitize.text.function = function(x) {x},add.to.row = list(
        pos = list(0),
        command = c(
          "&         &&\\multicolumn{2}{c}{n=50}&&\\multicolumn{2}{c}{n=200}&&\\multicolumn{2}{c}{n=1000} \\\\
          \\cline{4-5} \\cline{7-8} \\cline{10-11}
          Parâmetros & VV & Clear & Média & EQM& Clear & Média & EQM& Clear & Média & EQM\\\\"
)))
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the function [`print.xtable`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xtable/versions/1.8-2/topics/print.xtable), there is different `sanitize` function to add markup in the table. You can have a look at the part *4.1 Markup in table* in the *The xtable Gallery* vignette ( `vignette("xtableGallery")` )

For your code, you have **first** to escape the latex command (your `parameter variable` (i.e `$\\gamma 0 (\\mu 2)$`) and **seconde** then to sanitze your print.xtable call with the argument `sanitize.text.function = function(x) {x}`

For your example, to make it reroducible, don't forget to explain the file your are using and to call the packages and libraries.

As a .Rmd file, this give *mutatis mutandis*

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(xtable)

url <- 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/master/'
dt1 <- read.table(paste0(url, 'sim50.txt'), header = TRUE)
attach(dt1)
dt2 <- read.table(paste0(url, 'sim200.txt'), header = TRUE)
attach(dt2)
dt3 <- read.table(paste0(url, 'sim1000.txt'), header = TRUE)
attach(dt3)

gamma0=1.23
gamma1=0.07
gamma2=1.05
#gamma3=0.7
beta0=1.18
beta1=0.23
beta2=0.25
phi1 <- 0.69
rho <- 0.03
truevalue <- c(gamma0,gamma1,gamma2,beta0,beta1,beta2,phi1,rho)

eqm=function(x,theta){ 
  N=length(x)
  sqrt(sum(((x-theta)^2))/N)}
m  <- dt1
m2 <- dt2
m3 <- dt3

eqmest=c(eqm(x=m[,1],theta=truevalue[1]),
         eqm(x=m[,2],theta=truevalue[2]),
         eqm(x=m[,3],theta=truevalue[3]),
         eqm(x=m[,4],theta=truevalue[4]),
         eqm(x=m[,5],theta=truevalue[5]),
         eqm(x=m[,6],theta=truevalue[6]),
         eqm(x=m[,7],theta=truevalue[7]),
         eqm(x=m[,8],theta=truevalue[8]))

eqmest2=c(eqm(x=m2[,1],theta=truevalue[1]),
          eqm(x=m2[,2],theta=truevalue[2]),
          eqm(x=m2[,3],theta=truevalue[3]),
          eqm(x=m2[,4],theta=truevalue[4]),
          eqm(x=m2[,5],theta=truevalue[5]),
          eqm(x=m2[,6],theta=truevalue[6]),
          eqm(x=m2[,7],theta=truevalue[7]),
          eqm(x=m2[,8],theta=truevalue[8]))

eqmest3=c(eqm(x=m3[,1],theta=truevalue[1]),
          eqm(x=m3[,2],theta=truevalue[2]),
          eqm(x=m3[,3],theta=truevalue[3]),
          eqm(x=m3[,4],theta=truevalue[4]),
          eqm(x=m3[,5],theta=truevalue[5]),
          eqm(x=m3[,6],theta=truevalue[6]),
          eqm(x=m3[,7],theta=truevalue[7]),
          eqm(x=m3[,8],theta=truevalue[8]))
parameter <- c("$\\gamma 0 (\\mu 2)$","$\\gamma 1 (\\mu 2)$", "$\\gamma 2 (\\mu 2)$", "$\\beta 0 (\\mu 1)$", "$\\beta 1 (\\mu 1)$","$\\beta 2 (\\mu 1)$","$\\phi 1 (sd)$","$\\rho (cor)$")
dt <- data.frame(Parameters=parameter,VV=truevalue,Mean=cbind(colMeans(dt1)),EQM=eqmest,Mean=cbind(colMeans(dt2)),EQM=eqmest2,Mean=cbind(colMeans(dt3)),EQM=eqmest3)

print(xtable(dt,digits=c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5), caption = "",align = rep("c",9)), 
      caption.placement = "top", include.rownames = FALSE, type = "latex", 
      sanitize.text.function = function(x) {x})
```
````

[image: output]